# javascript within an iframe, redirect

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am new to javascript. I have the script bellow for  website

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.idxhome.com/site/listing/gallery/slider/86841?hid=493156&effect=fade&auto=true"&maxResults=5">
</script>
```

this is a real state property gallery within an iframe, what I need to know is how to re-direct this to the target property (on Click) but to a new window.

how can i do that?

Comment: I don't even see the script; can you post it?

Comment: Do you mean when you click the `iframe` it redirects the user?

Comment: This is the script: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.idxhome.com/site/listing/gallery/slider/86841?hid=493156&effect=fade&auto=true"&maxResults=5">
</script>  this is a slide gallery for real estate properties, normally when you click the picture in the gallery it takes you to the details of the specific property. i need to see the details in a new window on the browser - Thanks

Comment: Is the link even a JavaScript file?

Comment: yes, it is an external java script

Comment: i dont have access to the script, the code was provided to me by a 3rd party company

Comment: First of all, why are you using a script provided to you by a third-party company, and second of all, are you trying to redirect an `iframe`?